# style of selector does not work

Tags: android, android-selector

my style for text

```
<style name="TextStylePressed">
    <item name="android:textSize">20px</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

My selector arrow.xml where I use a style

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item style="@style/TextStylePressed">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90.0" android:endColor="#F1F4F2" android:startColor="#F1F4F2" android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dip" android:topLeftRadius="7dip" />
        </shape>
     </item>
</selector>
```

and a list of where I use the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="wwwwww" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:minHeight="20dp" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

as you can see the style has not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`android:state_pressed="true"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to your selector item.

EDIT: I also came across this **exact** problem the other day. Try setting [`android:duplicateParentState="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#duplicateParentState) in the views that need to have their states duplicated. It worked for me the other day.

Comment: is no difference At least change the text in one of the buttons

Comment: There are other states in the link that I posted, have you tried them all? I'm not sure if that button you posted is hovered/focused or not. Keep in mind that you need to have different items for every state combination.

Comment: I added style = "@ style / TextStylePressed" all variants but the style is not working, do not change the text style

Answer (score 0):

- Your arrow is supposed to become a particular style when it gets pressed;
- Your arrow is used as background for linear layout;
- Questions: - have you set linear layout to be clickable?
            - are you changing the arrow style via Java? [If yes, please provide code sample].

Comment: I completely change my style with the selector, I showed the basic version of the selector.